# Turn off C++ new operator exceptions globally

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, exception, std

Is there any way to globally switch off exceptions for the `new` operator?
And if there's more than one, which is the best?

I tried this but I'm really not sure in this:

```
#include <new>
using std::nothrow;
```

I tried googling for "using std::nothrow;", but there are no results.

I'm using MSVC 2010.

Of course I know `new (std::nothrow) myClass();`

Comment: I removed that. I considered mainly the first part and I'm sorry my idea does not work ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. This would break a lot of code, for instance in the standard headers, which does rely on `new` throwing.

The C++ committee is aware of the danger introduced by standardizing dozens of almost-compatible languages under a single name, and with just 5 such options you already would have 32 incompatible languages.

Comment: You can ensure that you'll never get a `std::bad_alloc`, by setting a new handler.  But this function cannot cause `operator new` to return a `nullptr` when there is no more memory.  It is only allowed to return if it has made more memory available; otherwise, there would be exactly the problem you state: all of the standard library would break.  (Most applications _should_ probably install a new handler; unless you have some real strategy for recovering from `bad_alloc`, it's better to terminate the program immediately.)

Answer (score 0):

```
#define NEW1(type, ...) new (std::nothrow) type(__VA_ARGS__)
#define NEW(type, size, ...) new (std::nothrow) type[size](__VA_ARGS__)
```

//Usage:

```
int *a=NEW1(int),     //single non-initialized int
    *b=NEW1(int, 42), //single int with value 42
    *c=NEW(int, 42);  //array of ints made of 42 elements

delete a;
delete b;
delete[] c;
```

Comment: Hi. Please do not recommend solutions that use macros to write code, unless this is specifically asked for, by the question. Doing what you propose, creates client code that uses `NEW` and `NEW1`, which will force your entire code base to support these macros, for the project's lifetime. Thinking "just create a macro" creates cruft (and permanently increases the effort required to understand the code, for the entire codebase).

Comment: This is an interesting and tricky solution. But yes, I cannot add this to my project ... and as far as I know the best is to avoid the usage of macros.

Comment: This by definition doesn't turn off exceptions _globally_ but only where the macro is used. The macro adds no value over explicitly specifying `std::nothrow`, but it does create confusion for the maintenance programmers.